# Scala: create instance by type parameter

Tags: scala

I am trying to create a generic method to create class instance by specified type parameter.

Code change conditions: 
* as minimum as possible changes to P1 - P3 classes
its a legacy code an code below is just a prototype, ideally no changes at all to these classes.

See my code below.

```
trait P {
  def run() : Unit = ???
}

class P1 (cfg : String ) extends P {
  override def run() : Unit = {
    println("1")
  }
}

class P2 (cfg : String )extends P {
  override def run() : Unit = {
    println("2")
  }
}

class P3 (cfg : String ) extends P {
  override def run() : Unit = {
    println("3")
  }
}



  def executor[T <: P](cfg: String): Unit  = {
    new T(cfg).run()
  }

executor[P1]("someCfg")

executor[P2]("someCfg")

executor[P3]("someCfg")
```

Here is error I am getting:

```
Error:(26, 10) class type required but T found
    new T(cfg).run()
        ^
Error:(53, 10) class type required but T found
    new T(cfg).run()
        ^
```

Comment: You'll have to help the compiler. How about something like: `def executor[T<:P](cfg: String)(fn: String => T): Unit = fn(cfg).run()`. And then use it like `executor("someCfg")(new P1(_))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def executor[T <: P](cfg: String)(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): Unit  = {
  tag.runtimeClass.getConstructor(classOf[String]).
    newInstance(cfg).asInstanceOf[T].run()
}
```

And use it:

```
executor[P1]("someCfg")
executor[P2]("someCfg")
executor[P3]("someCfg")
```

Reading http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html and simply searching for `ClassTag` and `TypeTag` will give you more information.

However, this is less safe than the solution given in the other answer: it'll fail at runtime if the class doesn't have a constructor taking `String`.

Answer (score 3):

Information about `T` is lost in runtime due to **type erasure**, therefore you **cannot instantiate it**.

In order to satisfy your requirements with minimal changes of `P1` - `P3` classes you would have to pass some kind of factory function to `executor`:

```
  def executor[T <: P](cfg: String)(fct: String => T): Unit = {
    fct(cfg).run()
  }
```

In this case calling side would change to this:

```
  executor("someCfg")(new P1(_))

  executor("someCfg")(new P2(_))

  executor("someCfg")(new P3(_))
```

with no changes to `P1` - `P3` classes.

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: I was hoping that there is some kind of magic trick so its can be by passed... thanks anyway

Comment: It is jvm limitation so I doubt that it can be avoided

Comment: It can, actually. See my answer.